# unexpected keyword argument, 'text'

Tags: python

I am new to design Python Graphics. I am trying to run the below code but it gives a strange error. Can anybody help me out with this error?

```
from livewires import games, color
SCREEN_WIDTH=640
SCREEN_HEIGHT=480
my_screen=games.Screen(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT)
wall_image=games.load_image("wall.jpg", transparent=False)
my_screen.set_background(wall_image)
games.Text(screen=my_screen, x=500, y=30,
           text="Score: 1756521", size=50,
           colour=color.black)
my_screen.mainloop()
```

and on executing this I'm getting the below error:

```
Exception NameError: "global name 'screen' is not defined" in <bound method Text.__del__ of <livewires.games.Text object at 0x02B14810>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\game_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    colour=color.black)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

As a matter of fact, I looked at the source code of livewires games.py module and is as below

```
class Text(Object, ColourMixin):
    """
    A class for representing text on the screen.

    The reference point of a Text object is the centre of its bounding box.
    """

    def __init__(self, screen, x, y, text, size, colour, static=0):
        self.init_text (screen, x, y, text, size, colour, static)
        .........
```

So where am I going wrong???

Comment: Livewires is awful. It simply restricts the functionality of Pygame as Pygame restricts the functionality of SDL. At best, I say stick with Pygame.

Answer (score 0):

> `from livewires import games, color`

No such module `color`, but `colour` [[proof link]](http://github.com/livewires/python/blob/master/module/livewires/colour.py)

> `"C:\Python31\game_test.py"`

Please read module [docs](http://github.com/livewires/python/tree/master/module). I don't think it supports python3.

> The package has been used on versions of Python from 1.5.2 to 2.4, but the games module now uses PyGame which requires at least version 2.1. Release 2.1 experienced some compatibility problems with Python 2.3 and later (or more specifically Tk8.4 which those include) which are hopefully corrected by this revision.